# Applying a function on an F# array

Tags: arrays, f#

```
type Sizes = 
| Big 
| Medium 
| Small
;;

//defines cup/can/bottle with size
type Containment = 
| CupDrink of s:Sizes
| CannedDrink of s:Sizes
| BottledDrink of s:Sizes
;;

// defines record for each type for drink
type Coffee = {DrinkName : string; price: double  }
type Soda = {DrinkName : string; price: double }
type Brew = {DrinkName : string; price: double }

// union for type of drink
type liquid = 
| Coffee of c:Coffee
| Cola of s:Soda
| Beer of b:Brew
;;

let Guiness = Beer {DrinkName = "Guiness"; price = 0.15}
let CocaCola = Cola {DrinkName = "Cola"; price = 0.15}

let smallCup = CupDrink Small // it could be just containment | size
let bigBottle= BottledDrink Big


let findPricePrML(dr:liquid) =
     let price = 0.0
     match dr with 
    |Beer(b=h)->  h.price 
    |Cola(s=h) ->h.price 
    |Coffee(c=h)  -> h.price 
    |_-> failwith "not found"
// returns size in ML fro each  size available // asuming that small bottle , can and cup have same size,
//if not another kind of program can be made but it's not part of the assingment
let find size = 
    match size with
    |Big -> 250.00
    |Medium -> 125.00
    |Small -> 75.00
```

```
let grandTotal (dr:liquid ,cont:Containment) = function
     (*let temp = {dra=dr;conta = cont} //supossed to search on menu list if such item exists (can't figure the syntax)
     if List.contains temp menuList then *)
    |CupDrink (s=z)  ->  findPricePrML dr * find z
    |BottledDrink (s=z)  ->  findPricePrML dr * find z
    |CannedDrink (s=z)  ->  findPricePrML dr * find z
    |_-> failwith "not found"
    (* else failwith "no such item exists"*)
   ;;

let source =  [|(CocaCola, bigBottle); (CocaCola, smallCup); (Tuborg, smallCup)|]

let Test =

    Async.Parallel [ async { return Array.map grandTotal source } ]
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Hello, I'm trying to learn basics of CPU bound parallel programming in F#. Here I have a function that calculates drink prices. And all i want is to apply another function(which multiplies the result with a certain number) to the results i get from the parallel calculation but I keep getting type mismatch errors. In my solution the result i get is a jagged array. Unfortunately i couldn't figure out how to get the results just as an array too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the first issue with your code is that your `grandTotal` function takes two arguments:

```
let grandTotal (dr:liquid, cont:Containment) = function
  | ...
```

This means that you have to call it with something like `grandTotal (CocaCola, bigBottle) drinkKind`. However, in your code that tries to call this, you use:

```
Array.map grandTotal source
```

This calls `grandTotal` with only a single argument - an item from the `source` list, so you get back a function rather than a price. You probably need something like:

```
Array.map (fun drink -> grandTotal drink kind) source
```

The second issue is that you are not really parallelising anything. The way you use `async`, you are just creating a single computation and then running that on a background thread. You could do something like:

```
let test =
    [ for a in source -> async { return grandTotal a kind } ]
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

However, a more efficient and simpler approach is to use `Array.Parallel.map`:

```
Array.Parallel.map (fun drink -> grandTotal drink kind) source
```

To answer your question about calling another function - this is impossible without seeing a more complete code sample that we can run.